# Unable to start remote session

Tags: powershell, winrm

I am having bad time to identify the root cause of the following error.

So far I checked everything that I know but not able to find the solution. I disabled Windows Firewall to rule-out firewall issues. The two system are part of same domain.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

```
$credential=Get-Credential -UserName "domain.local\user.surname" -Message "Test" 
$remotesession=New-PSSession -ComputerName "XX-XXX-XXX" -Credential $credential -Authentication Default
Enter-PSSession -Session $remotesession
```

> New-PSSession : [XX-XXX-XXX] Connecting to remote server XX-XXX-XXX
>   failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the
>   operation. Verify that the  specified computer name is valid, that the
>   computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception
>   for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access  from this
>   computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles
>   limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For
>   more information,  see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Result of `winrm get winrm/config/client`

```
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = REMOTESERVER.DOMAINNAME.LOCAL
```

Result of `netsh winhttp show proxy`:

```
Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Direct access (no proxy server).
```

Result of `winrm quickconfig`:

```
 WinRM service is already running on this machine. WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

Comment: Check `wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts` See here for details https://www.vultr.com/docs/executing-remote-commands-in-powershell

Comment: Forgot to mention. These servers are Azure VMs